# Может ли скрипт срабатывать неправильно из-за большой нагрузки на сервер?

Tags: php, хостинг

С сайта контакты в amoCRM добавляется через раз.

Проверил кучу раз скрипты, всё верно. Ошибок нет.
Плюс ко всему, думаю, что если в скрипте ошибки, 
то контакты не будут передаваться вообще.
Может ли проблемой быть высокая нагрузка на сервер?

И вообще, высокая ли это нагрузка? Хостинг самый дешевый:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код самого файла, передающего сделки и контакты:

```
    <?php
$leads['request']['leads']['add']=array(
  array(
    'name'=>$new_lead_title,
    'status_id'=>7829006,
    'responsible_user_id'=>$lead_user_new,

    'custom_fields'=>array(

     array(
        'id'=>1404981,
        'values'=>array(
          array(
            'value'=>$form
          )
        )
      ),

      array(
        'id'=>1404975,
        'values'=>array(
          array(
            'value'=>$_POST['city']
          )
        )
      ),

      array(
        'id'=>1404977,
        'values'=>array(
          array(
            'value'=>$_POST['urlsite'] 
          )
        )
      ),

      array(
        'id'=>1404979,
        'values'=>array(
          array(
            'value'=>$_POST['keyword']
          )
        )
      )

    )
  )
);

$link='https://'.$subdomain.'.amocrm.ru/private/api/v2/json/leads/set';
$curl=curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'amoCRM-API-client/1.0');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($leads));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);

$out=curl_exec($curl);
$code=curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
CheckCurlResponse($code);

$Response=json_decode($out,true);
$newleadid = $Response['response']['leads']['add'][0]['id'];

$contact=array(
            'custom_fields'=>array()
        );

    if(!empty($_POST['phone']))
    $contact['custom_fields'][]=array(
        'id'=>1138130, 
        'values'=>array(
          array(
            'value'=>$_POST['phone'],
            'enum'=>'OTHER'
          )
        )
      );

    if(!empty($_POST['email']))
    $contact['custom_fields'][]=array(
        'id'=>1138132, 
        'values'=>array(
          array(
            'value'=>$_POST['email'],
            'enum'=>'OTHER'
          )
        )
      );

if(isset($contactid) && !empty($contactid))
{
$contact['linked_leads_id'] = Array($newleadid);
$contact['id'] = $contactid;
$contact['last_modified'] = time();
$contact_params=Array();
$contact_params['request']['contacts']['update'][]=$contact;
}
else
{
$contact['name'] = "Новый клиент";
$contact['responsible_user_id'] = $lead_user_new;
$contact['linked_leads_id'] = Array($newleadid);
$contact_params=Array();
$contact_params['request']['contacts']['add'][]=$contact;
}

$link='https://'.$subdomain.'.amocrm.ru/private/api/v2/json/contacts/set';
$curl=curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'amoCRM-API-client/1.0');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($contact_params));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);

$out=curl_exec($curl);
$code=curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
CheckCurlResponse($code);

?>
```

Comment: Отчего нет? Хотя вероятнее ОС сервера недовольство проявит. Или сам сервер. Или интерпретатор. Стукачей много, короче говоря :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, судя по этим цифрам, сервер обрабатывает 100.000 запросов в день.
Скорее всего, это вместе со статикой, но для "самого дешевого" хостинга уже должно быть впритык.

Отсутствие ошибок 503 говорит только о криворуковсти авторов CMS. Традиционный для похапешников подход - ошибки либо давить ошибки вообще, либо выдавать с 200 кодом.

Если "С сайта контакты добавляется через раз" (фраза, **абсолютно** ничего не говорящая постороннему человеку, с тем же успехом можно было написать "мопсики пякают через раз") то ошибки **обязательно** есть. Другое дело, что по хорошей похапешной традиции они либо задавлены напрочь, через проставленную от большого ума `error_reporting(0)`, либо выводятся куда угодно, но только в не в **лог файл.**

"если в скрипте ошибки, то контакты не будут передаваться вообще" - это заблуждение. Ошибки происходят не только от кода, но и от окружения, в котором он работает. Если, к примеру,  на хостинге база данных периодически пишет ошибку Too many connections (и ничего в БД не записывается), то на домашнем компьютере получить такую ошибку практически невозможно. При том что код в обоих случаях один и тот же.

В общем, без сообщений об ошибках гадать о причинах бессмысленно. Поэтому:

1. Нужно добиться вывода всех ошибок в error_log. В простом случае это задается директивой `log_errors`. В случае готовой CMS надо разбираться, как там у нее внетри все устроено.
2. Задать уровень отображения ошибок

   ```
   error_reporting(error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE)
   ```

и смотреть ошибки в логе ошибок веб-сервера.

Comment: "Похапешники" оскорблены! Криворукие везде есть.

Comment: Сайт без CMS, вывод ошибок включен. Если что-нибудь в скриптах начудить, то он выдаёт ошибки. Но в моём варианте ошибок не выдает, и сервер ошибок не возвращает. Прикрепил код файла к вопросу.

Comment: «Отсутствие ошибок 503 говорит только о криворуковсти авторов CMS.» — 502/503 всегда отдаёт сервер, когда до этой самой CMS не может достучаться, не?

Comment: А как в php с многопоточностью?

Comment: А для чего она конкретно в этом случае?